# Join table on multiple ids

Tags: php, mysql

exp table: This is where I store entries while keeping the domains and sub domains in a separate table. The `sub_domain` column can have one or multiple ids that match the `id` column in `misc`.

```
+----+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | job_type  | experience | exp_title | domain | sub_domain  | start      | end        |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 83 |     268 | Full Time | dasdfg     | dest      | 76     | 89,91,93,95 | 07/15/2012 | 07/31/2012 |
| 84 |     269 | Full Time | abcdef     | title     | 77     | 89          | 07/15/2011 | 07/31/2011 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

misc table:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------+--------------+
| id  | name                                   | category     |
+-----+----------------------------------------+--------------+
|  89 | Name1                                   | category    |
|  91 | Name2                                   | category    |
|  93 | Name3                                   | category    |
|  95 | Name4                                   | category    |
|  55 | Name5                                   | category    |
```

I was wondering how to change `LEFT JOIN misc c ON a.sub_domain=c.id` if there are more than one sub_domains in the exp table while keeping in mind that there can be one id as well.

```
$query_str = "SELECT a.*, b.name, c.name AS sub_name
            FROM exp a 
            LEFT JOIN misc b ON a.domain=b.id
            LEFT JOIN misc c ON a.sub_domain=c.id
            WHERE a.user_id = ?";
```

Comment: Consider restructuring your tables from [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) to [2NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to have columns with comma separated values. Read the answer on the question:

**[Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)**

Short answer is: **It's really that bad.**

---

Until you fix the design, you can use the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
$query_str = "
        SELECT a.*, b.name, c.name AS sub_name
        FROM exp a 
          LEFT JOIN misc b ON a.domain = b.id
          LEFT JOIN misc c ON FIND_IN_SET(c.id, a.sub_domain) 
         WHERE a.user_id = ?
             ";
```

Comment: What should be used instead of commas?

Comment: Another table to store the one-to-many (or many-to-many) relationship between domains and subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query_str = 
    "SELECT a.*, b.name, c.name AS sub_name 
    FROM exp a  
    LEFT JOIN misc b ON a.domain=b.id 
    LEFT JOIN misc c ON locate(concat('','',c.id ,'',''),'','',a.sub_domain,'','') >0
    WHERE a.user_id = ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do this in two queries. One of the main reasons is that if ever you manage to accomplish what you want to do, you'd be returning rows with practically the same data except for the `sub_name` column. That's really unnecessary.

You can first `JOIN` the two tables on `a.domain = b.id` and then construct a second query that uses an `IN(...)` statement for all the subdomain values. It'd be something like this:

```
$subdomains = explode(',', $data_from_first_query['sub_domain']);
if (count($subdomains)) {
  $q2 = '
    SELECT
      b.name
    FROM 
      misc AS b 
    WHERE b.id IN ('.implode(',',array_fill(0, count($subdomains), '?')).')';
}
```

Then use foreach to bind values in your placeholder.

But then again, it is good practice to make sure your database is normalized.